# How to reverse Bitcoin Elliptic curve?

Tags: security

Hello Friends is this possible to reverse the elliptical curve if you have value of X and Y of public key?

I know the public is generated through following formula
K=k*G or k*G=K

Can we reverse it ?

Comment: Are you understand that if it is possible to reverse the elliptic curve point multiplication, the security of Bitcoin would be equal to zero, so now when market price is above 30k, I think that reverse slightly impossible nowadays.

Comment: I think you are asking whether you can calculate a private key from a public key. If this was possible Bitcoin would be broken as all funds associated with a public key could be stolen by anyone.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The whole point of Elliptic Curve Cryptography is that it is not possible to do such an operation. If it were, ECC would be broken, along with everything that uses it.

With current technology and algorithms, it is not possible to do what you are asking.